# How to get ip adress of the domain using url in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, dns, ip

I want to get ip adress from url in android.How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"); 
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
```

And make sure you have internet permission.

Comment: I tried that codes.first line is working but second line is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes, it throws exception.

Comment: try {
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"); 
   String ip = address.getHostAddress();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }

Comment: can you send an example. harunkaraca19@yandex.com.tr on facebook